# Phantom BigCommerce Template Parts

Tags: bigcommerce

I recently upgraded one of our store (article15clothing.com) to use a custom Stencil theme we developed. I am having a weird issue (that appears like) with old template parts outputted from the old BluePrint theme, like previous embed code into the footer. Has anyone else seen something like this or know how to get rid of it?

Comment: what are you not expecting to be output?

Comment: For example, we used to use SnapEngage. It was hard encoded into our footer by a previous developer under BluePrint. I have no call to it in my new Stencil template or footer script box on the backend (or none that I can see). It has appeared on our page.

Comment: It wasn't hardcoded in the footer, it was hardcoded into the web analytics box which is called within stencil.

Comment: @Alyss I was not aware. How do I disable their output? I am completely not see any reference to SnapEngage from my end anywhere (?).

Comment: Disregard last. Found it user Advanced.